# How to highlight a comment in mcedit?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, mc, mcedit

I need to highlight comments on mcedit using syntax file.
One line comment begins with "--" and may end with "\n" or with "--".
My syntax file content which responsible for comments is following:

```
context -- \n brown
    spellcheck

context /\* \*/ brown
    spellcheck
```

Example of one line comments is here:

```
-- This line starts with comment
this is code -- This is another comment, which ends with '\n'
this is another code -- This is another comment, which ends with '--' -- this is another code after comment
```

How to highlight one line comment that may end with "\n" or with "--"?

Comment: my similar solution, but on objective-c, i think it helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030552/whats-a-good-regular-expression-for-comment-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score -1):

This question is probably more suited to [superuser](http://superuser.com), however:

Based on [the man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mcedit1.html), I would try:

```
context linestart -- \n brown
    spellcheck

context linestart -- -- brown
    spellcheck
```

Comment: On mc internal editor's syntax file can't contain more than one 'context' tag which starts with the same symbols. Therefore I should use regular expression in this situation. I've already tried these syntax:

context -- \[\n|--\] brown
    spellcheck


Anybody know what reg-exp should I use?

Comment: Thank you for response Casper. But lines may not start with comments.

Comment: @user694192 regarding your regexp question: "The wildcard may be used within context delimiters as well, but you cannot have a wildcard as the last or first character." (man mcedit) The `[]` character class apparently is also considered wildcard, which makes your problem impossible to solve in current MCEdit.